# how to get checkbox value in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox, html-input

My HTML script is

```
<html>

    <body>
    <b><font color="green">Please select a check box to change the color of text </font> </b><br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="red"  id="chkbx" > &nbsp; Red<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="green" id="chkbx" value="1"> &nbsp; Green <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="blue" id="chkbx" value="2"> &nbsp; Blue <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="orange" id="chkbx" value="3"> &nbsp; Orange <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="yellow" id="chkbx" value="4"> &nbsp; Yellow <br>
    <p id="demo"></p>

    <button onclick="myfunction()">My Choice</button>
<br><br>
    <h style="color: red; font-weight: bold;"> </h>
    <p id="demo"></p>
```

i need to get the checkbox value in javascript and if any one checkbox is selected that colour will apply to a text to display on the output. how to do?

Comment: Seems that radio buttons might be better for this.

Comment: The attribute id should be unique

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please remember to always check the helpful descriptions that appear when selecting tags.  This will help you select tags that help categorize your question.  Tags aren't keywords!  Don't just stuff your tag list with the same words that are in your question title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off - don't use the  tag as it has been deprecated since 1999 use

```
<p style='font-weight:bold; color:green'>....</p>
```

Instead of checkboxs use radio buttons

```
<input type="radio" name="red" value="red" onClick="myFunction(this.value);"> &nbsp; Red<br>
```

Repeat the above for all possible selections.
Change your function `myFunction()` to `myFunction( value )` and work from there. The information is passed directly to the function so there is no need to go looking for it.

Comment: thank you jeff. one morething i want to display a text as colour what selected in radio button how to do ? thanks.

Comment: The text for the whole page or just the text in a specific area of the  page?