# how to get only one radio button value in javascript

Tags: javascript, checkbox

```
<input type="radio" name="red"  value ="red"  onclick="myFunction(this.value);"id="chkbx" /> &nbsp; Red<br>
    <input type="radio" name="green"  value ="green" onclick="myFunction(this.value);"id="chkbx" > &nbsp; green<br>
    <input type="radio" name="yellow"  value ="yellow " checked onclick="myFunction(this.value);"id="chkbx" > &nbsp; yellow<br>
    <input type="radio" name="orange"  value ="orange" onclick="myFunction(this.value);"id="chkbx" > &nbsp; orange<br>
    <input type="radio" name="blue"  value ="blue" onclick="myFunction(this.value);"id="chkbx" > &nbsp; blue<br>
    <p id="demo"></p>
button onclick="myfunction(this.value)">My Choice</button>
<br><br>

    <p id="demo"></p>


    <script>
    function myFunction(chkbx)
     {
      if(chkbx.checked)
     {
       chkbx.checked = false;
     }
     else
     {
      chkbx.checked = true;
     }
```

The Thing is " I want to get the colour from radio button apply to a text in output screen(at a time one radio button would be select).What can i do. Please give some idea. i am new to javascript. I want in javascript only.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to get checkbox value in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21668843/how-to-get-checkbox-value-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.Value` will return you the value:

```
function myFunction(chkbx)
{
   if(chkbx.checked)
   {
      alert(chkbx.value);
   }
}
```

Comment: starty ourchat if you are free bro

Answer (score 0):

Give all the radio buttons in the group the **same** `name`.

Answer (score 0):

Radio buttons allow the user to select only ONE of a predefined set of options. You define groups with the name property (radio buttons with the same name belong to the same group).
So to solve your issue, you can do as belows.

```
<p><input type="radio" name="color"  value ="red"><i>Red</i></p>
<p><input type="radio" name="color"  value ="green"><i>Green</i></p>
<p><input type="radio" name="color"  value ="yellow" checked><i>Yellow</i></p>
<p><input type="radio" name="color"  value ="orange"><i>Orange</i></p>
<p><input type="radio" name="color"  value ="blue"><i>Blue</i></p>
```